# Dynamically add page-breaks to html with variable amount of sections of variable sizes

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, page-break

I'm trying to solve this current problem which I could use some help with:
From the database using php, the page must load an X number of sections, every section has some content on top, a table and some content on the bottom, the table can have 0 to any number of rows, depending on what was previously in the database.
Aside from the table the rest of the content doesn't vary in size.

I cannot know beforehand what will be the size of each section because of the table, and there is usually at least 30 sections.

This page must be print friendly, and aside from the page-breaks everything is already working.

I need to find a way to dynamically add page-breaks to fit the sections into the page without cutting them between pages.

The code is about 400 lines so it wouldn't be practical to post it here, but the section structure is something like this:

```html
<section class="row">
<section>
 <section class="col-md-2"></section>
 <section class="col-md-8 printcenter">
  <p class="docenteheader" >
   <span class="tabspaceright">NAME: <strong>name</strong></span>
   <span class="tabspaceleft">ID: <strong>number</strong></span>
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>1:</strong></th>
   <th><strong>2:</strong></th>
   <th><strong>3:</strong></th>
   <th><strong>4:</strong></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p><strong>Something1:</strong> Something</p>
  <p>
   <span><strong>Something2: number</strong></span>
   <span ><strong>Something3: number</strong></span>
  </p>
  <section class="rel_endline"></section>
 </section>
 <section class="col-md-2"></section>
</section>                       
</section>
```

I removed the css classes and original names and PHP code to facilitate viewing

Comment: This will likely be handled by either PHP or JS code, so please include your PHP code. What you would do in your PHP is... you probably output sections in a `for` or `while` loop right? So you simply track how many times you're looping, and add in page breaks every time `$i % 2 == 0` if you want a page break every other loop. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does makes sense, thank you for replying, but it doesn't help, since sometimes i would have to page-break after 1 loop, sometimes after 5, or 3 or any number really, because the size of the sections change...

Comment: Where could I put the PHP code? its quite huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my problem was caused not by the faulty page breaks, but I had negative margins in an element, that messed the entire way page breaks work, by removing that, it worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample PHP code, let me know if anything is unclear. I tried to use self-explaining variable names.

```
<?php

    $PAGEBREAK_LENGTH = 1000; // Add a page break every 1000 characters.
    $lengthTracker = '';

    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
        $lengthTracker .= $row['article']; 
        $lengthSize = strlen($lengthTracker);

        if ($lengthSize > $PAGEBREAK_LENGTH) {
            echo '<div class="page-break">This is a page break</div>';
            $lengthTracker = ''; // Reset length tracker since we just added a break
        }

        echo '<div class="article">';
        echo $row['article'];
        echo '</div>';
    }

?>
```

If you include the `if ($lengthSize > $PAGEBREAK_LENGTH)` before echoing the article, you will tend to include page-breaks "more often." If you include the `if` statement after the article is echod, you will have page-breaks less often (so you'd have potentially bigger blocks of text).

Experiment with both ways to see which style you prefer, since you (presumably) can't include page breaks mid-article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer HC_

Comment: i got it to work on firefox, but chrome eats away all my sections in half even though every single dom in the entire site is float:none and position:relative and all sections set to page-break-inside: avoid

Comment: @RicardoMelo I would have to see a pastebin to be able to help with that. It sounds like you may have preset heights or something.

Comment: It was a very strange problem, the split doubled in size after each page break and I fixed it with something very far from elegant, after each break I added a section with min-height of 1cm*number of breaks, and now it works fine on chrome too